# Route change not logging in console NextJS + TypeScript

Tags: typescript, next.js

I am trying to add a Loading bar to my NextJs project but two things are not happening.

1. When I try to log a router event when I navigate to a new route, nothing logs.
2. When I try to add a loading bar on navigating to a new route, it does not work.

This is what I have in my _app.tsx

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import type { AppProps } from "next/app";
import "./global.css";
import { useRouter } from "next/router";
import NProgress from "nprogress";
import "nprogress/nprogress.css";

export default function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }: AppProps) {
  const router = useRouter();

  useEffect(() => {
    const handleStart = (url: string) => {
      console.log(`Loading: ${url}`);
      NProgress.start();
    };
    const handleStop = (url: string) => {
      console.log(`done: ${url}`);

      NProgress.done();
    };

    router.events.on("routeChangeStart", handleStart);
    router.events.on("routeChangeComplete", handleStop);
    router.events.on("routeChangeError", handleStop);

    return () => {
      router.events.off("routeChangeStart", handleStart);
      router.events.off("routeChangeComplete", handleStop);
      router.events.off("routeChangeError", handleStop);
    };
  }, [router]);
  return (
      <div id="root" suppressHydrationWarning>
        <Component {...pageProps} />
      </div>
  );
}
```

So I created a dummy NextJS project without using TypeScript, which has the following in _app.js

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import '../styles/globals.css';
import Layout from '../components/layout/Layout';
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';
import Router from 'next/router';
import NProgress from 'nprogress';
import 'nprogress/nprogress.css';
Router.events.on('routeChangeStart', () => NProgress.start());
Router.events.on('routeChangeComplete', () => NProgress.done());
Router.events.on('routeChangeError', () => NProgress.done());

NProgress.configure({ showSpinner: false });

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  const router = useRouter();

  useEffect(() => {
    const handleStart = (url) => {
      console.log(`Loading: ${url}`);
      NProgress.start();
    };
    const handleStop = (url) => {
      console.log(`done: ${url}`);

      NProgress.done();
    };

    router.events.on('routeChangeStart', handleStart);
    router.events.on('routeChangeComplete', handleStop);
    router.events.on('routeChangeError', handleStop);

    return () => {
      router.events.off('routeChangeStart', handleStart);
      router.events.off('routeChangeComplete', handleStop);
      router.events.off('routeChangeError', handleStop);
    };
  }, [router]);
  return (
    <Layout>
      <Component {...pageProps} />
    </Layout>
  );
}

export default MyApp;
```

In my Dummy project, the loading bar works and I get the logs[image: Routing logs]

What could I be missing in my `_app.tsx`

Comment: Using TypeScript or JavaScript is unlikely to be the reason for your problem. Are both projects using the same version of `next`? If they do, try to do the same things you do in `_app.js` but just in `_app.tsx`. Since any JavaScript code is also valid TypeScript code, I would expect that to work.

Comment: Hi Jonathan. No they are not using the same very in of next.. The one with Typescript is version 12.2.5 while the one with JS is 10.0.6.

Answer (score 0):

I created a brand new Next project with Typescript and copied your code from above. I created a new route and used it to navigate from '/' route. When I enter the new route in the url like "localhost:3000/hey" it works like a  tag and refreshes the page so it actually logs to console for a split second before it gets erased because of page refresh. When I used the  tag that Next provides, everything gets logged to the console because  tag doesn't refresh the page but it re-renders the page so the state is preserved. Hope that this will help you.

Comment: Hi Mert, thanks for the tip. That does help me.. Let me create a new project and see that in action. I'm not sure what you mean by tag

Comment: Tag means whatever is in <this-part></> so p tag is a paragraph and an a tag is a anchor which is <a></a>.  Try to navigate programmatically using nextjs <Link> tag. import Link from "next/link"; <Link href="/">Go</Link><Link href="/hey">Back</Link>